# Regex Queries for Lines

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a couple regular expressions for the below cases:

- Lines with a length divisible by n, but not by m for integers n and m
- Lines that do not contain a certain number n of a given character,
  but may contain more or less

I am a newcomer and would appreciate any clarification on these.

Comment: Please, post a pattern or string then you want to match, and, what you've tried so far to archieve your goals.

Comment: The first bullet point might not be possible with regex, since it can't (AFAIK) count characters.  The second might be possible with some sort of lookaround.

Comment: Do you know how to do the first part of the first expression, i.e. match a string with a length that’s a multiple of n?

Comment: Yes, it would be (for instance, for the character X) (?:X{2}). However, this would not exclude the case of divisibility by m.
For the second point, I've tried something like (\d{4,})|(\d{0,2}), where it ORs occurrences from 0-2 and then from 4 upwards, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Do you know how to negate a match, e.g. match any strings that are *not* the letter “a” repeated?

Comment: What is up with all the spam?

Comment: For negating a match, it would be (?:[^X]{2}), but again this is only for lengths of a multiple of 2 and does not exclude multiples of 3 etc. which is also required.

Comment: That’s not how you would negate a match in general. I was going for [negative lookaheads](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used JavaScript for my examples.

For the first one the key is to note that 'multiples' are just repeats. So using `/(...)+/` will match 3 characters and then repeat that match as many times as it can. Each matching group doesn't need to be the same set of 3 characters but they do need to be consecutive. Suitable anchoring using `^` and `$` ensures you're checking the exact string length and `?:` can be used to negate.

e.g. Multiple of 5 but not 3:

```
/^(?!(.{3})+$)(.{5})+$/gm
```

Note that JavaScript uses `/` to mark the beginning and end of the expression and `gm` are modifiers to perform global, multiline matches. I wasn't clear what you meant by matching 'lines' so I've assumed the string itself contains newline characters that must be taken into consideration. If you had, say, and array of lines and could check each one individually then things get slightly easier, or a lot easier in the case of your second question.

Demo for the first question:

```js
var chars = '12345678901234567890',
    str = '';

for (var i = 1 ; i <= chars.length ; ++i) {
    str += chars.slice(0, i) + '\n';
}

console.log('Full text is:');
console.log(str);

console.log('Lines with length that is a multiple of 2 but not 3:');
console.log(lineLength(str, 2, 3));

console.log('Lines with length that is a multiple of 3 but not 2:');
console.log(lineLength(str, 3, 2));

console.log('Lines with length that is a multiple of 5 but not 3:');
console.log(lineLength(str, 5, 3));


function lineLength(str, multiple, notMultiple) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('^(?!(.{' + notMultiple + '})+$)(.{' + multiple + '})+$', 'gm'));
}
```

For the second question I couldn't come up with a nice way to do it. This horror show is what I ended up with. It wasn't too bad to match n occurrences of a particular character in a line but matching 'not n' proved difficult. I ended up matching `{0,n-1}` or `{n+1,}` but the whole thing doesn't feel so great to me. I suspect there's a cleverer way to do it that I'm currently not seeing.

```js
var str = 'a\naa\naaa\naaaa\nab\nabab\nababab\nabababab\nba\nbab\nbaba\nbbabbabb';

console.log('Full string:');
console.log(str);

console.log('Lines with 1 occurrence of a:');
console.log(mOccurrences(str, 'a', 1));

console.log('Lines with 2 occurrences of a:');
console.log(mOccurrences(str, 'a', 2));

console.log('Lines with 3 occurrences of a:');
console.log(mOccurrences(str, 'a', 3));

console.log('Lines with not 1 occurrence of a:');
console.log(notMOccurrences(str, 'a', 1));

console.log('Lines with not 2 occurrences of a:');
console.log(notMOccurrences(str, 'a', 2));

console.log('Lines with not 3 occurrences of a:');
console.log(notMOccurrences(str, 'a', 3));


function mOccurrences(str, character, m) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('^[^' + character + '\n]*(' + character + '[^' + character + '\n]*){' + m + '}[^' + character + '\n]*$', 'gm'));
}

function notMOccurrences(str, character, m) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('^([^' + character + '\n]*(' + character + '[^' + character + '\n]*){0,' + (m - 1) + '}[^' + character + '\n]*|[^' + character + '\n]*(' + character + '[^' + character + '\n]*){' + (m + 1) + ',}[^' + character + '\n]*)$', 'gm'));
}
```

The key to how that works is that it tries to find n occurrences of `a` separated by sequences of `[^a]`, with `\n` thrown in to stop it walking onto the next line.

In a real world scenario I would probably do the splitting into lines first as that makes things much easier. Counting the number of occurrences of a particular character is then just:

```
str.replace(/[^a]/g, '').length;

// Could use this instead but note in JS it'd fail if length is 0
str.match(/a/g, '').length;
```

Again, this assumes a JavaScript environment. If you were using regexes in an environment where you could literally only pass in the regex as an argument then it's back to my earlier horror show.

Comment: Yes, your explanations make sense. Thanks!

Comment: However, your second regex doesn't seem to work for me. 
For instance, for excluding lines with 3 instances of 'a', the regex would be:
^([^a\3]*(a[^a\3]*){0,(3 - 1)}[^a\3]*|[^a\3]*(a[^a\3]*){(3 + 1),}[^a\3]*)$

However, this does not detect those lines on https://regexr.com/.

Comment: @ACoder Don't confuse `\n`, which matches a newline, with the variable `n`. I tried to use the same variable names as the question but to make my answer clearer I'll change `n` to `m`. You also seem to have written `3 - 1` instead of `2` and `3 + 1` instead of `4`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, I changed the regex to:
^([^a\n]*(a[^a\n]*){0,2}[^a\n]*|[^a\n]*(a[^a\n]*){4,}[^a\n]*)$

It does seem to work on other sites than regexr.com